# Trouble displaying ColdFusion Results in proper order when Field length varies 101 vs 1000

Tags: mysql, sorting, coldfusion, sql-order-by

I'm using MySQL.  I have a table with a field called UnitName.  I just want to display all the UnitNames in order.   The Unit Names can vary:

```
101
T-101
G-202
1005
O-1305
```

When I display them using ORDER BY UnitName, The results are not sorted properly.  For instance 1000 will come before 101, T-2000 will come before T-201.   If they were all numeric values, I would try to use CAST(UnitName AS INT), but unfortunately I have to deal with the Alpha (and other '-') characters.

I believe the way to approach this is to make sure that the UnitNames have the same length, and then they will sort properly.   So basically I am trying to insert a number of zeros into the middle of the string until the lengths are identical and then ORDER BY that.

My query currently is listed below.

```
<cfquery name="Get"datasource="rent">
    SELECT * FROM Units
     ORDER BY Left(UnitName,2)+#RepeatString(0, 10-'LEN(UnitName)')#+right(UnitName, 'LEN(UnitName)'-2)   
</CFQUERY>
```

I'm basically saying sort by "the 2 left characters of the string+(a number of 0s determined by the number 10 minus the length of the string)+the characters on the right side of the string (except the first 2).

When I just do a CFOUTPUT of this the UnitName comes out perfectly. I do have to had some # to make it work:  #Left(UnitName,2)##RepeatString(0, 10-'#LEN(UnitName)#')##right(UnitName, len(UnitName)-2)#

But the query fails to execute as written below.   I've narrowed it down to the middle section where I'm trying to determine the number of Zeros to insert.   Specifically if I use:

`#RepeatString(0, 10-5)#`, the query will execute.  But the minute I put 'LEN(UnitName)' instead of 5, the query fails.   Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Any insight is appreciated--I've been banging my head against a wall.

Comment: Are the values of `UnitName` always either numerical or some characters followed by a dash followed by a number?

Comment: What is the expected output? Do you want all the numbers first then characters-numbers mix or vice versa?

Comment: Ignoring the quotes, `LEN` is a CF function. You cannot apply CF functions to a database column. CF does not know anything about your db. It just builds the SQL string and hands it off to MySQL. If you need to manipulate the values inside the db table, you must use [MySQL functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html).  (Though even using db functions, I am not sure the overall logic holds for all of the sample values you listed...)

Comment: Step 1.  For the values you posted, tell us the correct sort order and the reasons why.

Comment: The Order in the table might be:  101
T-101
G-202
1005
O-1305

Comment: Thank you for the insight into LEN not being MySQL.  Based on that I’ve changed the ORDER BY syntax to:

ORDER BY Left(Replace(UnitName,'-',''),2)+REPEAT('0', (10-CHAR_LENGTH(UnitName)))+Right(Replace(UnitName,'-',''), CHAR_LENGTH(Replace(UnitName,'-',''))-2)

The Query runs, but the sort order does not quite work because I believe it is only sorting by the first part of the Sort Order Left(Replace(UnitName,'-',''),2), which equates to the first two characters from the left of the Unit Number as opposed to the FirstTwoCharactersoftheUnitName+ANumberof0s+RemainingCharactersoftheUnitName

Comment: I believe it truncates the + and everything after.   Perhaps I’m using the wrong syntax for Order BY.   If I remove the “+” the query will not run.   


The order in the table might be:
110
101
101B
101A
T-110
T-101
O-1401
G-202
1005
O-1305

Comment: I would like the results to be
101
101A
101B
110
1005
G-202
O-1305
O-1401
T-101
T-110

In other words, the Numbers should be treated as Numeric.   All numbers should be prioritized first.   101 should appear before 1105 becuase as a Number 101 is lower than 1105.  If an Alpha charcter appears after the number, then it should be priotized after the number.  For instance 101A should appear before 101B, and 102A would appear after 101B.  If the Unit Number starts with a Letter, all of those should be grouped together with the Alpha character in Alphabetical order (i.e.. A101 appears before B101,

Comment: B101 would appear After A110.

I’m lost—Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Finally solved this.  I essentially broke it up into two queries.  I first do a query to determine if the UnitName is AlphaNumeric or just Numeric,  I then run one query if it contains alpha characters, and a different one if I have just Numeric entries.  That seems to work.